# Multiplying Polynomials using Linked List

Tags: java, linked-list

I'm trying to implement a method that multiplies two Polynomials as lists and returns a new list as the result. 
Here's what I have so far:

```
private PolyNode multiply(PolyNode first, PolyNode second) {
    PolyNode temp = new PolyNode(0, 0);
    PolyNode res = temp;

    while(first!=null) {
        while(second!=null) {
            //Multiply first term with all the terms with all terms in the second.
            temp = new PolyNode(first.coef * second.coef, first.power + second.power);
            temp = temp.next;
            second = second.next;
        }
        //Move to next term
        first = first.next;
    }
    return res.next;
}
```

But when I print the list, it doesn't show anything. The printing method works properly for my Addition, Subtraction, and First Derivative methods. It's just my Multiply method that's not working. 
Here's my printing method:

```
void printPoly(PolyNode curr) {

    if(curr == null) {
        return;
    }

    while (curr != null) {
        if(curr.power == 0) {
            System.out.print(curr.coef + "");
            curr = curr.next;
        }
        else if(curr.power == 1){
            System.out.print(curr.coef + "x ");
            curr = curr.next;
        }
        else {
            System.out.print(curr.coef + "x^" + curr.power + " + ");
            curr = curr.next;
        }
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Any thoughts? Thanks!

Comment: The first obvious thing to check is whether `curr` is null.

Comment: Thanks! I added if curr == null, return;

Comment: I actually meant to check it by printing out a big warning message like "Hey, why are you trying to print a null object?"

Answer (score 0):

```
PolyNode temp = new PolyNode(0, 0);
PolyNode res = temp;
```

Then

```
temp = new PolyNode(first.coef * second.coef, first.power + second.power);
```

So `res` is pointing to some object. `temp` is now pointing to some new object unrelated to res.

Then

```
return res.next;
```

I'd assume this is `null`?

Basically you aren't actually doing anything with the results
 just playing with temporary variables which you throw away.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to finish my method, so here it is!

```
private PolyNode multiply(PolyNode first, PolyNode second) {
    PolyNode temp = new PolyNode(0, 0);
    PolyNode res = temp;

    while(first!=null) {
        while(second!=null) {
            //Multiply first term with all the terms with all terms in the second.
            temp.next = new PolyNode(first.coef * second.coef, first.power + second.power);
            temp = temp.next;
            second = second.next;
        }
        //Move to next term.
        first = first.next;
    }
    return res.next;
}
```

And here's my print list method:

```
void printPoly(PolyNode curr) {

    if(curr == null) {
        return;
    }

    while (curr != null) {
        if(curr.power == 0) {
            System.out.print(curr.coef + "");
            curr = curr.next;
        }
        else if(curr.power == 1){
            System.out.print(curr.coef + "x ");
            curr = curr.next;
        }
        else {
            System.out.print(curr.coef + "x^" + curr.power + " ");
            curr = curr.next;
        }
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Feedback on best practices are GREATLY appreciated!